# Resultado query MySQL diferente localhost e produção

Tags: mysql

Estou com um problema no qual a mesma query executada no servidor local e produção, retornam um resultado diferente. A versão de produção está vindo incompleta no campo AVALIACOES.
Verifiquei a versão do mysql do servidor e local e são diferentes.
Pq deve estar acontecendo este problema? Segue os dados para análise:

---

QUERY

```
SELECT A.*,
       L.nome AS localidade,
       CA.nome AS cargo,
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( AT.id, '=', AT.telefone, ';', AT.observacao ) SEPARATOR '{{separador}}' )
            FROM tal_a_c_alunos_telefones AS AT
            WHERE AT.aluno_id = A.id  
        ) AS telefones,
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( T.nome SEPARATOR ', ' )
            FROM tal_a_c_turmas_alunos AS TA
            LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_turmas AS T
            ON TA.turma_id = T.id
            WHERE TA.aluno_id = A.id  
        ) AS turmas,
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( C.nome SEPARATOR ', ' )
            FROM tal_a_c_turmas_alunos AS TA
            LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_turmas AS T
            ON TA.turma_id = T.id
            LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_cursos_turmas AS CT
            ON T.id = CT.turma_id
            LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_cursos AS C
            ON CT.curso_id = C.id
            WHERE TA.aluno_id = A.id
        ) AS cursos,
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( C1.nome, '{{td}}' , AV.nome, '{{td}}', AV.peso, '{{td}}', AA.nota ) SEPARATOR '{{tr}}' )
            FROM tal_a_c_alunos_avaliacoes AS AA
            LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_avaliacoes AS AV
            ON AA.avaliacao_id = AV.id
            LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_cursos AS C1
            ON AA.curso_id = C1.id
            WHERE AA.aluno_id = A.id
        ) AS avaliacoes,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM tal_a_c_alunos_avaliacoes AS AA
            LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_avaliacoes AS AV
            ON AA.avaliacao_id = AV.id
            LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_cursos AS C2
            ON AA.curso_id = C2.id
            WHERE AA.aluno_id = A.id
        ) AS avaliacoes_realizadas,
        DATE_FORMAT( A.data_inicio, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS data_inicio,
        DATE_FORMAT( A.data_conclusao, '%d/%m/%Y' )  AS data_conclusao
FROM tal_a_c_alunos AS A
LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_localidades AS L
    ON A.localidade_id = L.id
LEFT JOIN tal_a_c_cargos AS CA
    ON A.cargo_id = CA.id
ORDER BY A.nome
```

---

LOCALHOST

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

RESULTADO:
Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}O papel do aluno{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}Chamada Virtual{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}Lema do Grupo{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}Quem são os meus colegas?{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}Enquete{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}TeleListas Site**{{td}}Criando Domínios{{td}}1{{td}}6.75{{tr}}TeleListas Site{{td}}Composição Editorial{{td}}2{{td}}8{{tr}}TeleListas Site{{td}}Avaliação Final{{td}}1{{td}}8{{tr}}TeleListas Site{{td}}Por que uma empresa precisa ter um site?{{td}}2{{td}}10{{tr}}TeleListas Site{{td}}Por que as empresas não obtêm o sucesso esperado na internet?{{td}}2{{td}}10**

** A parte em negrito está faltando no resultado da produção*

---

PRODUÇÃO

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

RESULTADO:
Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}O papel do aluno{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}Chamada Virtual{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}Lema do Grupo{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}Quem são os meus colegas?{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}Sensibilização para EaD{{td}}Enquete{{td}}1{{td}}10{{tr}}TeleListas Site

Comment: Os dados podem estar diferentes. Por isto a Consulta retornou resultados diferentes?

Comment: Os dados estão iguais. A única diferença é na versão do MYSQL. Acredito que esteja relacionado a algum bug do mysql ou configuração de buffer.

Comment: Como você sabe que os dados estão iguais na base? Como você está obtendo estes dados pra comparação (formulário no aplicativo, select por linha de comando...)?

Comment: Eu importei os dados da produção para o localhost.
Os dados são solicitados pelo sistema por uma requisição em ajax.
Estou comparando através do sistema, console e phpmyadmin. E estão retornando o mesmo.

Comment: @RobertoPC Através do sistema, console e phpmyadmin, os dados são os mesmos. Ok. E quando não são? Através de qual método de comparação os dados não coincidem?

Comment: Então, as 3 maneiras estão retornando o problema.
No localhost está vindo completo o campo e na produção está incompleto.
O banco é o mesmo e a query tb. A única diferença ao meu ver é de versão, onde na produção está um pouco mais atualizado.

Comment: @RobertoPC Eu ia sugerir olhar o tamanho do conteúdo da coluna (select `LENGTH(AVALIACOES)` e `select CHAR_LENGTH(AVALIACOES)` mas não achei esta coluna na query. Ela é o resultado daquela subquery com `GROUP_CONCAT`? Engraçado, pelo conteúdo retornado, não parece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema adicionando a seguinte linha no início da query:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1024000;
```

Seguindo a orientação desse post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52441/selecting-multiple-columns-from-multiple-rows-in-one-column-subquery